# IIS 7.5 Virtual Directory getting Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Tags: iis-7.5, credentials, virtual-directory

I have a web application that is trying to access images from a shared folder on a different server.

In my web app, I created a new virtual directory.  The alias is QCPhotos and the path is \alta\QCPhotos.  Alta is a different server than my web server, which is Brighton.

I am getting the error:

**401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.**

In trying to debug, on the Alta server, I have given the Everyone user full access to this folder.  I also gave {domain}\Brighton$ full access to the folder.

I turned on Directory Browsing, and that seems to work fine.  I can list the contents of the folder, but as soon as I click on a jpg image, this error comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm still not sure why it wasn't letting me access, but I created a domain user acct named QCPhotos.  I gave that user read permissions on the folder, and then set the virtual directory to use this user in IIS.  This fixed my problem.

Comment: I had the same problem, and specifically the PHP in my virtual directory said "No input file specified".  I gave a local user read permission to the directory, then set the Virtual Directory to connect as that user in IIS 7.  Now I don't get Access Is Denied, and the PHP files load!